# What methodology does proc varclus use to reduce the number of variables

Tags: pca, feature-selection, sas, discriminant-analysis

In statistics, we can use methods like principal component analysis, linear discriminant analysis for variable reduction. In SAS, there is a proc called VARCLUS which is used for variable reduction.

What methodology is it using under the hood, principal component analysis, LDA, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my SAS 9.4 documentation:

> "The VARCLUS procedure divides a set of numeric variables into
>   disjoint or hierarchical clusters. Associated with each cluster is a
>   linear combination of the variables in the cluster. This linear
>   combination can be either the first principal component (the default)
>   or the centroid component (if you specify the CENTROID option). The
>   first principal component is a weighted average of the variables that
>   explains as much variance as possible. See Chapter 79: The PRINCOMP
>   Procedure, for further details. Centroid components are unweighted
>   averages of either the standardized variables (the default) or the raw
>   variables (if you specify the COVARIANCE option). PROC VARCLUS tries
>   to maximize the variance that is explained by the cluster components,
>   summed over all the clusters.
>
> The cluster components are oblique, not orthogonal, even when the
>   cluster components are first principal components. In an ordinary
>   principal component analysis, all components are computed from the
>   same variables, and the first principal component is orthogonal to the
>   second principal component and to every other principal component. In
>   PROC VARCLUS, each cluster component is computed from a set of
>   variables that is different from all the other cluster components. The
>   first principal component of one cluster might be correlated with the
>   first principal component of another cluster. Hence, the PROC VARCLUS
>   algorithm is a type of oblique component analysis"

Comment: So what is this oblique component analysis and how it is different from principal component analysis?

Comment: Oblique is the rotation used on the factor scores.  It is essentially a special handling of PCA.  This site gives a nice overview:  http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/teachwiki/index.php/Oblique_Rotation_Methods_in_Factor_Analysis

Comment: Thanks. Is there a guide on when to use principal component analysis vs varclus?